# How constraining are conservation laws and continuity principles?

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, coordinate-systems, degrees-of-freedom

Suppose there are $N$ particles with masses $m_1, m_2, ..., m_n$. Consider the $3N$-dimensional classical configuration space of such particles. Consider some arbitrary physically possible trajectory $T$ in this configuration space which goes from time $t=0$ to $t = \infty$, where the only force acting on the $N$ particles is gravity via Newton's law of universal gravitation (and no two particles ever occupy the same point).

I'm interested in the following question. Consider some arbitrary initial segment of our trajectory $T$ (e.g. which goes from $t=0$ to $t=5$). Call it $T'$. Consider all possible continuations of $T'$ into an infinite trajectory from $t=0$ to $t = \infty$, which are such that (i) the positions and velocities of every particle evolve continuously and (ii) the conservation of energy, linear momentum, and angular momentum are obeyed. How constrained are these possible continuations? Clearly, $T$ is one such continuation. Are there others?

Comment: Doesn't this tie into how precisely you know the information at $t = 5$? If everything is absolutely deterministic down to infinite precision in all quantities, then there would only be one continuation. But if there are any uncertainties, then there's an infinite number of future trajectories?

Comment: Interesting - could you provide a proof that there would only be one continuation? Clearly there would be more than one continuation if we dropped either (i) or (ii).

Comment: I suppose it also depends on how long the known trajectory is relative to the time scales of the interactions... It's possible to find a huge number of trajectories that have what looks like a linear trajectory within some range, but are different functions. That's the basis of things like Taylor series approximation.

Comment: Can *I* provide one? No -- I'm not so good at rigorous proofs of things. Hopefully somebody comes along who can, though. If there are no uncertainties in anything measured, then I *think* your problem is entirely constrained to a single trajectory for all time as soon as you set the initial conditions. You don't even need the $T^\prime$ trajectory.

Comment: Well, we are only considering the force of gravity, which acts instantaneously in classical mechanics right? I would have thought that whether or not there is a unique continuation wouldn’t depend on the length of T’, as long as it had finite length.

Comment: If you know the exact position and velocity of every single particle and you assume the laws are exact, then you will only get one trajectory. Full stop. And that will be based only on those initial conditions.

Comment: I am not assuming the laws apply though. I’m considering all possible continuations of T’ that satisfy (i) and (ii) only, not ones that continue satisfying the deterministic laws

Comment: Conservation of energy, momentum, and mass (which you neglected -- not sure if that was an oversight or intentional) are all that is needed. Such a system will only have a single trajectory if those laws are obeyed and all information is deterministic. And it will all be based on the initial conditions only -- knowing $T^\prime$ doesn't provide any additional information. I guess I don't understand your question to know what "not assuming the laws apply" means while also saying that energy and momentums are conserved.

Comment: So, I'll have to back out of the conversation now. Hopefully somebody else understands what you are getting at and can answer it or help clarify.

Comment: What happens when there are several particles at the same/almost the same point. I think that case needs to be specified. Or you could specify how a NaN works physically I guess :-)

Comment: I was thinking that conservation of energy/momentum alone don’t imply the laws of physics...

Comment: Emil - I was assuming T was a physically possible trajectory where no particles ever occupy the same point. But that’s a good clarification.

Comment: @DavidB. In the classical sense, conservation of mass, energy and momentum *are* the laws of physics. But we know of times and cases where the classical case doesn't hold anymore and so those laws don't work. These aren't theory-of-everything equations, unless your "everything" is classical mechanics only.

Comment: I was thinking they can’t entail the classical laws on their own because one trajectory compatible with conservation of mass/energy/momentum is just where a bunch of particles stay still forever doing nothing. But that trajectory doesn’t obey Newton’s law of gravity (that’s why I let T’ traverse some finite time, to avoid this sort of example).

Comment: Conservation of momentum (and energy) includes body forces like gravity ($F = ma$ and gravity is an $F$) -- so if initially at rest, the body force will induce an acceleration and make things move. If there is a gravity field, particles initially at rest won't stay at rest. Maybe you need to clarify what you think the equations are and that would help somebody address your question?

Comment: If you assume (ii), then by Noether's theorem you're assuming that the laws of motion are invariant wrt displacement in time & space, and are isotropic.

Comment: So the N particles in your question are all gravitationally interacting, but you assume no knowledge of this interaction, only conservation laws? But then, you actually need to have the formula for energy on configuration space, so that you can identify equi-energetic curves. Similarly with momentum and angular momentum. I think these functions should lead to EoM (f.e. force is gradient of potential energy) which is deterministic. Therefore there should be only one (or none if i) is not satisfied) continuation?

Comment: @David B. *one trajectory compatible with ... bunch of particles stay still forever doing nothing* Interesting. So you don't want to apply knowledge of energy function as in my previous comment. Then the question is how many equi-energetic (is there a word for it?) paths there are that are also equi-momentum  and equi-angular momentum? (oh, the english...)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that there are potentially several continuations, although they are singular. In most cases, though, determinism is true.

In your question, you stated that there would not be any collisions. [The Painlevé conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painlev%C3%A9_conjecture) states that "For $N \geq 4$ the N-body problem admits noncollision singularities." This is known to be true for $N\geq 5$.

What this means is that there are trajectories in configuration space that do not tend to a definite limit as a certain point in time is approached. While storming off to infinity is one possible cause, another one is increasingly wild oscillations (this will still include [at least one inter-particle distance approaching zero](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.6313v1) with one particle escaping to infinity in finite time). So this leaves the subsequent trajectory apparently undefined.

[One can regularize beyond a 2-particle collision singularity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1208.6313.pdf), continuing trajectories deterministicaly (this makes sense mathematically in Newtonian mechanics, real physics would disagree). This does not work for 3- or more particle collisions, although [simultaneous 2-collisions can be handled](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82302066.pdf). I have not yet found a paper regularizing non-collision singularities but I *think* one can contrive such a configuration that this makes sense, and since it is wildly oscillating one can likely get non-unique continuations. It would be a pretty artificial case, of course.

[It has been conjectured that these bad behaviors have measure zero among the initial conditions](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/017e/e8b93ba69c11c117aadab9967abc17d92770.pdf), so most of the time the system is deterministic and the initial trajectory segment uniquely determines the entire future.

Conservation laws are insufficient for determining the $N$-body problem even without singularities since there are too few constants of motion compared to the degrees of freedom. Continuity principles on the other hand basically say you are not allowed to start in configurations that lead to singularities than break continuity.

Generally, Newtonian mechanics can be indeterministic in strange ways; see for example the [Norton's dome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton%27s_dome) thought experiment where there are apparently an infinite number of continuations from an initial condition without any infinite forces or collisions.